# How is data stored in kafka log files

Tags: serialization, apache-kafka

According to the documentation,kafka is persisting data in binary format regardless of the configured serializer.
I 'm sending a json messages.
Checking kafa log/data topic files, I can see my json message in raw/human readable format-is this expected?
I thought regarless of using stringserializer or bytearrayserializer, the result in the broker will be same.
Does this mean here that the storage will be more efficient when using byetarrayserializer than stringserializer?

Comment: How are you checking the content of the log files? Using `cat` or similar tool? If so, then that is why you can see the JSON, because `cat` interprets the byte content as UTF-8 String as much as possible. But it is a binary file still, even if it contains UTF-8 bytes. As to comparison between StringSerializer and ByteArraySerializer, the former accepts a String and returns a byte array of this string in UTF-8, and the latter accepts a byte array and returns a byte array. It depends on how you serialize String to a byte array (when using UTF-8 there will be no difference in the output).